# Need some explanation to this Problem.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I was reading a theorem which says :

> If  $ f \in L^p(\mathbb{R}^n) $ and $\Phi\in C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$ then $f_\epsilon= \Phi_\epsilon \star f$ tends to $f$ as $\epsilon \to 0$.

([here](http://www.mat.unimi.it/users/peloso/Matematica/ch1-2.pdf), page number 2). But I am not able to understand the steps. Can anyone explain it to me? I understood the procedure but I am not able to understand the steps. 
Thanks.

Comment: Which step is problematic to you? How far do you understand the proof?

Comment: I am not able to understand how the smooth function is convolved ,the first step itself i am not able to understand . I can corelate it with the standard convolving procedure. Can u help me?  :)

Comment: Page 3, first line. Is it ok?

Comment: Prof, No. How did that $a$ term disappear inside the integral ?

Comment: Think of it as $a=1$ for now, but

Comment: it is because $a=\int \varphi(y) dy$, and hence $af(x) = \int f(x)\varphi(y) dy$.

Comment: I am dumb :( in the next step i didn't undertand how $\tao_{tz}$ is introduced.

Comment: It is just a notation: $\tau_{tz}f(x) = f(x-tz)$, the translation of $f$.

Comment: After applying Minskawski's inequality it says that $||f||$ tends to zero as $t\to 0$ how is that ?

Comment: $(f(x-tz)-f(x))\to 0$ as $t\to 0$. Is this ok?

Comment: yes, sure ! But how can i say that $||f||$ goes to zero ?

Comment: It also says that $\|\tau_{tz}f-f\|\leq 2\|f\|$, meaning that this difference is bounded in norm.

Comment: You should look up the Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem, because it is used here.

Comment: Thank you so much :) I am happy that i understood something finally

Comment: Prof. do you have time to help me with the proof of denseness of $C^\infty$ in $L^p$  ( page 4) ? First of all i didn't even understand the procedure used here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the definition of the constant $a$ and of the convolution product, we have that
\begin{align*}
(f \ast \varphi_t)(x) - af(x) & = (f \ast \varphi_t)(x) - f(x)\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \varphi(y) ~dy \\
 & = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f(x - y)\varphi_t(y) ~dy - \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f(x)\varphi(y) ~dy.
\end{align*}
Now in the first integral, make the change of variables $y \mapsto tz$. Then $dy \mapsto t^n ~dz$ (because $tz = (tz_1, \dots, tz_n)$ and $dz$ is really shorthand for $dz_1 \cdots dz_n$ as we are working in $\mathbb{R}^n$) and
$$\varphi_t(tz) = t^{-n} \varphi\left( \frac{tz}{t} \right) = t^{-n}\varphi(z).$$
Hence the first integral becomes
\begin{align*}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f(x - y)\varphi_t(y) ~dy & = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f(x - tz)t^{-n}\varphi(z)t^n ~dz \\
 & = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f(x - tz)\varphi(z) ~dz.
\end{align*}
So, returning to our original calculation, we have
\begin{align*}
(f \ast \varphi_t)(x) - af(x) & = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f(x - y)\varphi_t(y) ~dy - \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f(x)\varphi(y) ~dy \\
& = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f(x - tz)\varphi(z) ~dz - \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f(x)\varphi(z) ~dz \\
 & = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} (f(x - tz) - f(x))\varphi(z) ~dz \\
 & = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} ((\tau_{tz}f)(x) - f(x))\varphi(z) ~dz \\
 & = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} (\tau_{tz}f - f)(x)\varphi(z) ~dz. \\
\end{align*}

Now $\|\tau_{tz}f - f\|_p \longrightarrow 0$ by "Exercise I.6" in the notes you linked. The rough idea of the proof is to use the density of $C_c(\mathbb{R}^n)$ (compactly supported continuous real-valued functions on $\mathbb{R}^n$) in $L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$. Given $\varepsilon > 0$, let $g \in C_c(\mathbb{R}^n)$ be such that
$$\|f - g\|_p < \varepsilon.$$
Clearly since $g$ is continuous, for $t$ small enough
$$\|\tau_{tz}g - g\|_p < \varepsilon.$$
Now we have that
\begin{align*}
\|\tau_{tz}f - f\|_p & = \|\tau_{tz}f - \tau_{tz}g + \tau_{tz}g - g + g - f\|_p \\
 & \leq \|\tau_{tz}f - \tau_{tz}g\|_p + \|\tau_{tz}g - g\|_p + \|g - f\|_p \\
 & \leq \|\tau_{tz}\|_{\text{op}}\|f - g\|_p + \|\tau_{tz}g - g\|_p + \|f - g\|_p \\
 & = \|f - g\|_p + \|\tau_{tz}g - g\|_p + \|f - g\|_p \\
 & < 3\varepsilon
\end{align*}
for $t$ small enough. Therefore
$$\|\tau_{tz}f - f\|_p \longrightarrow 0 \text{ as } t \longrightarrow 0.$$
Since
$$\|\tau_{tz}f - f\|_p \leq \|\tau_{tz}f\|_p + \|f\|_p = 2\|f\|_p$$
and
$$\|\tau_{tz}f - f\|_p \longrightarrow 0 \text{ as } t \longrightarrow 0,$$
the hypotheses of the Dominated Convergence Theorem are satisfied and hence
$$\|f \ast \varphi_t - af\|_p \longrightarrow 0 \text{ as } t \longrightarrow 0,$$
or in other words $f \ast \varphi_t \longrightarrow af$ in $L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$ as $t \longrightarrow 0$.

---

**Addendum:** $\tau_{tz}$ is the translation operator
$$\tau_{tz}: L^p(\mathbb{R}^n) \longrightarrow L^p(\mathbb{R}^n),$$
$$(\tau_{tz}f)(x) = f(x - tz).$$
To see why it has norm $1$, note that
\begin{align*}
\|\tau_{tz}\|_{\text{op}} & = \sup_{\|f\|_p = 1} \|\tau_{tz}f\|_p \\
 & = \sup_{\|f\|_p = 1} \left(\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} |(\tau_{tz}f)(x)|^p ~dx\right)^{1/p} \\
 & = \sup_{\|f\|_p = 1} \left(\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} |f(x - tz)|^p ~dx\right)^{1/p} \\
 & = \sup_{\|f\|_p = 1} \left(\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} |f(u)|^p ~du\right)^{1/p} \\
 & = \sup_{\|f\|_p = 1} \|f\|_p \\
 & = 1.
\end{align*}
Above I used the change of variables $x - tz \mapsto u$. So $\|\tau_{tz}\|_{\text{op}} = 1$ is really just a consequence of the translation invariance of the Lebesgue measure.

Comment: @ Henry I was looking at the proof of denseness of $C^\infty$ in $L^p$ ( page 4) . i couldn't understand . Can u explain?

Comment: @Ananda: I think that perhaps you should post your question about page 4 as a separate question, and try to specify what exactly you don't understand about it. In any case, I can help explain that proof.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion :)

Comment: T.Horton what is actually $||\tau_{tz}||$ and why is it's norm $1$.

Comment: @Ananda: See the Addendum in my answer that I have just made.

Comment: Why did u take sup norm ? Am i missing something here ?

Comment: Let $(U, \|\cdot\|_U)$ and $(V, \|\cdot\|_V)$ be normed vector spaces and $T: U \longrightarrow V$ a linear map. Then one equivalent way to define the operator norm of $T$ is by $\|T\|_{\text{op}} = \sup \{\|Tx\|_V : x \in U \text{ and } \|x\|_U = 1\}$. See here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_norm#Equivalent_definitions

Comment: T.Horton : Sir , You have assumed that $C_c^\infty$ is dense in $L^p$ but is there a way of doing it without assuming that $C_c^\infty$ densness in $L^p$ ? Because i want to use this to prove that $C^\infty_c$ is dense in $L^p$ .

Comment: Since lesbegue integration is translation invariant , fot t small enough can i conclude that $||\tau z f-f||$ tends to zero.